# make clean and how to use it properly

Tags: makefile, cmake

Suppose that I am working in a project that is VC'ed and each branch has a separate, uncorrelated feature. Now each time that I am changing branch, I do the "primitive" thing to wipe out the build directory and then build anew. I heard somewhere that this isn't actually necessary and I can reach the very same result with `make clean`.
I was unable to find online a descriptive guide on how to do that (e.g. in which directory I have to run the command etc). Could somebody provide some explanation on what it does and how to use it?

Comment: To be extra sure it's clear: `clean` is not some built-in feature of make.  It's just a target, like any other target, that your makefile must define.  So, to know what it does and how it works you should look at your makefile.  The fact that it's called `clean` is just a _convention_ there's no rule about that and absolutely nothing magical about it.

Comment: How `cmake` tag is related with the question? Do you use CMake for configure your project?

Answer (score 0):

There is no firm standard for what exactly `make clean` should do; but if the `Makefile` you are using contains a target with that name, it is fairly safe to assume that it does whatever makes sense for throwing out trivial junk which can be recreated.

An additional convention is to have `realclean` and/or `distclean` with even more aggressive pruning of artifacts which can be regenerated.  The Linux source tree famously has a still more potent cleaning target `mrproper` which is named after a brand of detergent (which I believe no longer exists, though [Mr. Muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr_Muscle) is conceptually the same).

Briefly, `make clean` can be expected to `rm` anything you can easily create again with `make`, while `make distclean` would be expected to clean out everything except what was in the original source tarball (so you'll need to run `configure` or `automake` or similar tools again if those are part of the build chain) and `make realclean` somewhere in between (so maybe remove backup files and targets which are expensive to regenerate, but don't necessarily go all the way to a pristine source tree).

Comment: Thank you. And in which directory should I run these? I suppose in the `build` directory...?

Comment: Depends on the `Makefile`; typically in the top-level directory.